# screen larger, fixed margins for QML buttons and images

Tags: qt, qml

currently I have a qml application with specific sets of margins for each image. They look perfectly on a specific width of a screen. However if the screen enlarges, it will get all messed up and scattered around. Because the margins are set to a specific number. What is a better solution to this problem in qml ? I tried to set `position: relative` but that did not work.

for example:

we have two buttons

```
Button1 {
        anchors {
            right: parent.right
            rightMargin: 175
            bottom: parent.bottom
            bottomMargin: 95
        }
    }


Button2 {
        iconNext: true
        anchors {
            right: parent.right
            rightMargin: 53
            bottom: parent.bottom
            bottomMargin: 95
        }
    }
```

These two buttons look superb on my screen. Terrible on a larger screen as they get parted away from each other.

What is a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be anchoring the buttons to each other, not both anchored to the parent, if you want them to maintain a certain distance from each other. Example:

```
Button1 {
    anchors {
        right: button2.left
        rightMargin: 50
        bottom: button2.bottom
    }
}


Button2 {
    id: button2
    iconNext: true
    anchors {
        right: parent.right
        rightMargin: 53
        bottom: parent.bottom
        bottomMargin: 95
    }
}
```

That will make the spacing between the two buttons consistent (in pixels), even if the buttons themselves get bigger or smaller.

Then if you want the spacing to be relative (that is, relative to the size of the buttons or the size of the screen) rather than fixed in pixels, you could do something more like this:

```
Button1 {
    id: button1
    anchors {
        right: button2.left
        rightMargin: width
        bottom: button2.bottom
    }
}


Button2 {
    id: button2
    iconNext: true
    anchors {
        right: parent.right
        rightMargin: width
        bottom: parent.bottom
        bottomMargin: height*2
    }
}
```

This will maintain the relative spacing of the buttons. As they get bigger or smaller, their spacing scales to match. You can use this general idea of relative spacing in other ways. For example, instead of basing the spacing on the buttons size, it can be based on the size of the enclosing item (e.g. `rightMargin: parent.width/10`), or the entire screen, etc.